# Asymptotic Growth of Function of Prime Counting Function

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Consider $f(x)$ defined by $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \pi\Big{(}\frac{x}{k}\Big{)}$$ Does there exist a function $g(x)$ be such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$I have tried $g(x)=c x \log(\log(x))$, yet this seems to grow slightly too slowly.

Comment: Have you tried bounding the sum above and below using (some refinement of) Chebyshev's inequalities?

Comment: You don't have many good reasons to look at this. The asymptotic is given by the function $g(x)$ such that $\zeta(s) \log(s-1) = s \int_1^\infty g(x)x^{-s-1}dx$ ie. $g(x) \approx \sum_{k < x} Li(x/k)$

Comment: @user1952009 What do you mean by "many good reasons"?  Are you just commenting on the lack of motivation in the OP's question?

Comment: @ErickWong In the theory of primes and $\zeta(s)$ there are no good reasons to look at this.

Comment: @user1952009 What do you mean the "theory of primes and $\zeta(s)$"?  If you mean analytic number theory, then I utterly disagree.  This is equivalent to counting the number of pairs $(n,p)$ such that $np \le x$, which is a perfectly reasonable thing that might arise naturally in an analytic calculation.  It's reminiscent of counting almost-primes up to $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sum is identical to $\sum_{p\le x} \lfloor \frac{x}{p}\rfloor$, so it is indeed asymptotic to $x \log \log x$ by [Mertens's second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems).

In fact we get the second-order approximation $x \log \log x + Mx$ where $M$ is the Meissel-Mertens constant.  The error term is $O(x/\log x)$ which matches the truncation error of removing the floor brackets from the sum.

Since $\log \log x$ grows quite slowly, perhaps this extra term is what gave you the impression that $c \log \log x$ was not adequate.